# Add column to MySQL result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to add a column to a Mysql result using a subquery,
Suppose i have a table 'Cars' and a table 'Cars usage'
Table Cars has a column "serial_number" and the Cars usage table has a column "serial_number" as well:
So i wanna generate a result with the car name as first column and car usage as second:

```
Table cars:
-model
-serial_number

Table carsusage
-date
-serial_number
```

What i would like to achieve would look like so:

```
Model | Usage count
--------------------
|bar   | 1500       |
|foo   | 700        |
```

Ideally i need a sub-query, that, while querying the cars table, spits a query to the Cars usage table counting:

```
SELECT model, serial_number AS sn,(SELECT COUNT(serial_number) FROM cars_usage WHERE serial_number=sn) FROM cars;
```

So basically i would like to use the serial_number AS sn as a local variable and add the result of the count operation as second column.
Any advice?
No that much experience with querying a db here.

Thx

Comment: you don't need a subquery unless this is homework..

Comment: i dont do homework since 4 years, a subquery is not required, i just did not know it was possible to do without

Comment: Good, I hate homework myself :) A join between the two tables on the serial_number column is what you need. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want usage per serial number:

```
select model, serial_number, count(*) from cars inner join carsusage on cars.serial_number=carsusage.serial_number where cars.serial_number=$var group by 1,2
```

or if you want usage per model:

```
select model, count(*) from cars inner join carsusage on cars.serial_number=carsusage.serial_number where cars.serial_number=$var group by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just try something like

```
SELECT model, 
    serial_number AS sn,
    (SELECT COUNT(serial_number) FROM cars_usage cu WHERE cu.serial_number=c.serial_number) 
FROM  cars c;
```

Where you provide aliases for the tables, and then prefix the fields with the aliases.

You could also try a LEFT JOIN (do be carefull of inner join, because if there a no usages, it will not return a 0 entry for that car).

```
select c.model, 
       c.serialnumber sn,
       count(cu.*) 
from   cars c LEFT join 
       carsusage cu on c.serial_number=cu.serial_number
GROUP BY  c.model, 
          c.serialnumber
```